# Do's and Don'ts of backgrounds (Print Design)

Tags: print-design, background

I guess I'm naturally inclined to throw a background onto the average print job straight away rather than designing using white space...I have a bad habit of just throwing some sort of coloured background on to most things and I'm not afraid of using Illustrator patterns as well (20% Opacity diamond pattern on top or something), and very subtle gradients. I'm never entirely happy with this so I'm looking for some tips.

Now basically if you were just going to use a coloured background, should you just put the colour on and that's it? Is minimalism the way to go? Do backgrounds require subtle gradients or a pattern? I guess I have a tendency to want to overdesign.

Anyway what sorts of things do you do with your backgrounds?

Comment: That C+M+Y+K<=200 (250)? (which causes the ink to dry too slow and penetrate...)

Comment: Are you referring to print advertisements or some other printed content?

Comment: There's no answer to this other than opinion.